# Problem setting parent with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I've been following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU) and around 10:16 he presses <kbd>Ctr</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to set the parent to armature with automatic weights. When I try to follow I don't get that same menu. I've checked that I'm in the correct mode and the correct objects are highlighted. What am I doing wrong?
[image: parenting armature to object]

Answer (score 7):

Select the object and the armature in this order; mesh, then armature. The armature must be the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217) to get the options you are looking for. You have the mesh as the active object.
(lighter orange color is the active object)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parent your armature to a curve, it wont work. At first you have to convert the curve to a mesh.

For that select the curve in *Object Mode*, *Object (at the top left) > Convert > Mesh*.

Now your curve isn't a curve any more, and you are able to parent it to the armature by automatic weights.

Answer (score -1):

I found that problem too and what I would do is **select the armature first** then **select the mesh second**, so both should be highlighted/selected now. Then press ctrl P and you should get the same menu that you saw in the video

(this had me stumped too)