# Which object should be selected when selected to active is check for texture baking?

Tags: interface, texture-baking

Which object should be selected when *selected to active* is checked for baking, the one I'm baking to or from? I can never remember which one.

Comment: Backing is blender is so not likeable, and even after reading this topic it goes wrong...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [active object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/introduction.html) is the same no matter what action you are performing in blender.
The active object is always the object you selected **last**.
When using the default theme, the active object is outlined in yellow, and all other selected objects are in orange.

If you selected your object in the wrong order, you can just <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the object again to make it the active object.

To remember the selection order for baking is simple when you know what the active object is. Just say *selected to active*. Now think, you are baking from the selected object to the active object.

Answer (score 1):

The object you're baking to is selected, quickest way to remember this is that the **active object** is the object you're *changing*

Comment: This is backwards, the *active* object is the one that is changing.

Comment: @gandalf3 ??? excatly

Comment: The object you want to bake *from* should be selected, not active..

Comment: Yes, they are all selected, so I'm using selected to mean active

Comment: Selected != active. They are two different things, only one object can be active, and it doesn't have to be selected to be active.

Comment: So what the verb for active...?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms quickest way to remember this is that the *active* object is the object you're changing.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Activate? I've never seen it used like that though, as you usually make the active object active by selecting it. However if you deselect it by pressing A, its still active. In your answer you used *selected* as an adjective, so I don't seen any problem with just s/selected/active?