# Blender game runs very slow

Tags: rendering, game-engine, baking, performance, optimization

I am making my first game in Blender, so being kind of newbie, but I notice that when I run it in the standalone player, it runs very slow and jerky (in the built-in also, but not as bad), like some hi-end fancy game, but it's simple and has a primitive graphic/texturing/shading, so why does it run so jerky?

I heard something about "baking", to help it get rid of real-time processing and stuff if that's the problem, but if I want to bake an image, for example the grass field, it says "No objects or images found to bake to".

I would be SO GLAD AND GRATEFUL if someone could help me. I like how I made this game so far, but this is a pain in the heart.

Thank you so much for your time!

Here are some screens :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: answer coming.. hold on

Comment: Allright, I count on you :))

Comment: If it wasn't Rasterizer, give me a shout.

Comment: Wow, it's the rasterizer, 96%. But  what is it  and what can i do about that...?

Answer (score 3):

You can always tell what it jacking up a game by turning on FrameRate/Profile, an option under the "Game" tab.

In realtime, it will dynamically calculate how much time blender is spending on each part of the game, and you can see what is causing problems, and what could be beefed up without issues.

[image]

I'm going to go ahead and take a wild guess that your scene is slowed down by "Rasterizer" or the rendering process. Why is this? You used basic meshes, simple graphics, and easy shading. So what is causing this kink?

It's the lights! if each one of you trees has it's own separate light, thats a whole different set of the same graphics that blender has to calculate.

You were right, fortunately, that this can be fixed *quite easily* with [texture baking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14416/what-does-baking-mean).
First of all, you will need to [pick a target image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23219/how-to-pick-target-texture-image-for-baking) that you want to bake your texture to. Then, under the render tab, hit bake. Once the bake is done, save it and apply it as a shadeless texture. All of the light will be on the ground, just like it was being actively rendered, but blender will be muuuuch happier. And we all know, when blenders happy, so are you.

[How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509)?

Comment: A quick test reveals that for each point lamp in my scene (and on a crappy computer) 4 extra milliseconds are taken on rasterizer, and that's just with the default cube! May not seem like alot, but it adds up *fast*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I saw that the problem is the rasterizer. So, is it in the rasterizer what handles the lights? Cand i do something else to free it up? It seems a lot of work to take care of all the lights by baking them down, plus the fact that i have to create way more lights soon...

Comment: And i really don't know how to bake textures, it seems chinesse to me... the refference links you gave to me are discussions started by some advanced users that are knowing already what's going on.

Comment: @Andrei added to the answer... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake/13509#13509

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this tomorow, it's late and i have to go to sleep. I will come back with updates.

Comment: Ok, it seems like serious work and i have to gain more knowledge in blender before i do i do this. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: It really isn't that hard, if you want to come over to [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) we can walk you through the process.