# Selecting part of a object for the UV map

Tags: uv, objects

I have selected the middle part of a sphere, as you can see in the picture. In the uv editor my result is now a beautiful square map.

I would like to keep this uv map result, and now select the whole sphere, without the uvmap changing, and use only that edited square uv map for the all selected sphere.

[image: sphere and UV map]

Comment: i was hoping there is a kind of way to lock or pin the new created square so that it stays square. when i go back to the sphere and now select the complete square , in stead of just the middle part , i would like to see that the uv map still shows up as that square that i have just edited.  is there a way the uvmap can stay in that square position look by a lock or pin or something , when i will change the selection on the sphere to " select all" you will see the sphere turns orange in complete, while the uv map stays square because of some lock, is there a way how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can unwrap the selected portion, like you have in your image while leaving all the rest of the UVs untouched.

Starting with the UV layout you have in your bottom picture, in the UV editor, press <kbd>P</kbd> to pin the UVs. That will keep them in that layout, but only for the UV *unwrap* operation. All the other operations will ignore the pins if you have the entire sphere selected. 
[image: UV map with pinned uvs]
In this picture I first unwrapped the middle part of the sphere using *Follow Active Quads* (the pinned rectangular UVs), then one at a time selected the top and bottom and unwrapped with *Project From View*.

Thus what you can do is when you UV wrap the sphere only select the pieces you want want unwrapped, leaving all the previously unwrapped sections deselected.

Comment: i cannot follow this , you say :"in this picture I first unwrapped the middle part of the sphere using Follow Active Quads (the pinned rectangular UVs)," .....i tried that ,so first i did the pin like in picture, that worked ok ,  , than i clicked U , and choose Follow Active Squads" just like you said , and than i got stuck  , because a message showed up : "Report Error - No active face "

Comment: if you select the faces with box select or a similar method there will not be a "active face". You will have to deselect a face and reselect that same face to make it the active face, same as the principal for a [active object](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. the non-unwrapped part will use the default mapping.