# Refresh the UV Map with a new topology

Tags: modeling, uv, topology, uv-image-editor

I will use an easy example to focus my problem.

I have a cylinder, with this unwrap below. I scaled and moved the islands in the UV layout in order to optimize my UVs.

**Right now, I don't want to modify my Uvs' island more . . . Suppose island's position and scale are perfect for my purposes. They have just to stay there.**

[image]

Here's the problem: I can't export my cylinder with this topology (problem of my engine) then I have to fix my mesh in this way:

[image]

**I didn't touch any mark seams during the process.**

My question is: is there a command or a path in order to refresh the UV map? I would like to "refresh" the UV map with the new topology for the top and bottom face of cylinder without doing again the unwrap and scale-move my island.

P.S. I don't want to move again my UVs' islands because I already created the texture (with the first UV) and I'm afraid of not bieng able to match all perfectly with a new unwrap.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you convert Ngon to trianglle fan ? If with Poke Faces then there shouldn't be any need to fix UV map, the poked faces will be there.

Comment: I delete the big face (delete only the face) - select the edges around - extrude them - Alt M - Merge in Center

Comment: In cases like this it's better to avoid deleting any geometry because it means no way to update UV map without unwrapping once more.. However you can unwrap only one face. Or pin everything you don't want to touch and unwrap. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26791/selecting-part-of-a-object-for-the-uv-map

Comment: That's wonderful !! I'll try using pin. If i unwrap a single face, with all the rest "pinned" do you think the face will be unwrap in the same inital position of the older uv map? Like in the example of the cylinder: how could be the workflow? @Mr Zak if you upload an answer will be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you have 2 options. One is to poke face, which will divide it without distorting UV map and second is to pin vertices of the UV map, do what you need to do with the face and unwrap everything again without moving UV map.
Here is how it's done:
[image]

Comment: Perfect this is the workflow @Mr Zan was talking about! Tahnk you so much!!