# Curving an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I'm modelling a light saber, and I want to curve the grip in the middle around the base.  What is the best method of doing this?  I've tried the screw modifier, and the simple deform modifier, but they haven't achieved the desired result.
[image: screen shot of blender showing the light saber and grip object]

Comment: use the curve modifier  ' on curve circle'

Comment: Okay, that worked pretty well.  Thank you.

Comment: How about using 'Object Offset' in Array Modifier? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html#object-offset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add a empty at the same location as your grip object via naping the cursor to selected with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, and then adding the empty <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty*.
2. Add a *[Simple Deform Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html#simple-deform-modifier)* to your grip object.
3. Set the simple deform modifier to *Bend*, the *Deform* to *360°*, and the *Origin* to the empty you just added.
   [image: modifiers]

If it looks good, great you are done, however if it is bending around the wrong axis, or is too big continue on to step 4.

4. Now the empty comes in to play. Rotate the empty -90deg along the X axis. The simple deform modifier bends around the Z axis, so rotating the empty by -90deg will align its local Z axis with the world Y axis. (you also could rotate your mesh in edit mode, but I find the empty more convenient.)
5. Now the grip should be looking something like this. (mine was too big)
   [image: too large grip on handle]
   To shrink (or enlarge) the grip's diameter you have many options. You could change the array count (but I'm assuming you do not want to do that), move the mesh in edit mode, or (best of all) move the empty along the global Z axis.

Do note that if you want to move the grip after you have the modifier set up and working at the right size, you will have to move both the grip and the empty. Which would be a good case for [parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217), be sure to have the empty as the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217).