# How to add same texture to multiple objects

Tags: texturing

How do I give all selected objects the same texture without manually applying the texture to each and every object? I am trying to get some sort of box texture onto all of these cubes:[image]

Any steps on how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apply texture to one of the cubes, then select all the cubes and the textured cube as last, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut and select **Object Data** from the menu.

Comment: If you pick "material" from that menu instead, it will just assign the mat without linking the shape data too.

Comment: @JtheNinja thats true in case if all the cubes are unwrapped

Comment: thanks i managed to get it. sorry for late response i lost my info for this account.

Comment: @JtheNinja That's exactly what I needed, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

For your particular situation where you have exactly the same object, I will recommend copying the object data. Doing so will copy any materials, and UV maps to all the cubes.

<sub>(as suggested by [Denis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28884/2217))</sub>
First select one of your cubes (say the top corner.) UV unwrap that cube, and create the material. Now select all the cubes, keeping the UV unwrapped cube as the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217), and then "link" the data. 3D view header *Object* > *Make Links...* > *Object Data*, or by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd>.
Now all your cubes share the same mesh data so if you make any changes to one, all get changed (same as if you had duplicated them with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>).

---

Your other option is to make a material that is not depend on a UV map, then just assign the materiel to all the cubes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Materials*.

The simplest way to create such a material would be to use Box mapping.
Here are the needed nodes and the setting for cycles.
[image: box mapping in cycles]

Here it is for the blender internal.
[image: box mapping in the BI]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.7x, click *Object > Make Links > Materials*.