# Adding materials to more than one object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects

Is it possible to add a texture or material to more than one object at a time?

Comment: Like all objects have the same material? The materials must be apply one time for each mesh. You cannot select multiple objects and apply one material to all of them like expected in other graphic software.

Comment: Add a material to one object. Then select all of the object (making sure the one with the material is the "active" object), hit CTRL-L and select "link materials"

Comment: @ajwood this could be an answer :-)

Comment: [similar question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28883/2217)

Comment: Could you provide some more info about your current setup? E.g. What render engine you are using?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible link the materials on a selection of objects to a single "active" object.

1. Add an material to an object:
   [image]
2. Select all of the objects you want the material on, then select the object from step 1 (it's important that you select that object last; it needs to be the active object). Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select `Materials`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is an easy way to copy a material to many objects.
First the object with the material should be the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217) while all the other objects you want to copy the material to are selected. Then press the *"Copy Material to Others"* button in the material tab of the property window.
[image: copy material button]

---

[image: animated gif showing the process]

Answer (score 3):

For 2.8+ you can go to the *3D View* header menu *Object > Make Links > Materials*

[image]

You can also access it from the material slots dropdown *Copy to Selected* option

[image]

Materials are always copied from the active object to the others selected. <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking on an already selected object makes it the active one.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can select all those objects you want to assign material to and execute the code:

```
#assuming there's image loaded in Blender and called 'sky_1'. It's the one you'd like to assign
img = bpy.data.images['sky_1.jpg']
imageTexture = bpy.data.textures.new('Image_Texture', type = 'IMAGE')
imageTexture.image = img

#check presence of material with the same name
if bpy.data.materials.get("textureMaterial") is not None:
    materialToApply = bpy.data.materials["textureMaterial"]
else:
  # create material
  materialToApply = bpy.data.materials.new('textureMaterial')
  materialTexture = materialToApply.texture_slots.add()
  materialTexture.texture = imageTexture
  materialTexture.texture_coords = 'UV'
  materialTexture.mapping = 'FLAT' 

#loop through selected objects and assign the material
for x in bpy.context.selected_objects:
  me = x.data
  me.materials.append(materialToApply)
```

The small advantage of this (at least for me, I always check twice which one is active if transfering materials) is that it doesn't really matter the objects' selection order in this case.