# Can multiple meshes and textures share one material?

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, materials, unity

I am going to begin work on a game and was curious to know if I had 6 meshes (limbs) on one armature(think armors and equippables)? like each has an animation and own texture but the material shared by all of the other meshes(limbs). Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Adding textures to more than one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/adding-textures-to-more-than-one-object/34346#34346)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to give a bunch of objects the same material. If each is unwrapped that may complicate things. I think this may be what you are looking for
[image: one cube with material]
[image: Open Materials menu]
[image: Both objects share the same material]

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Hi Luke S. thats exactly wht i was looking for. i didnt reply because i was still doing research on other things. i still am and havent began on my models because i want to be sure of what i am doing. You said it would complicate things if i were to unwrap them right. I dont really get how to keep items unwrapped and give them their own texture while keeping the material the same. I tried to do that but i think it required me to make a new material if i wanted to apply a texture and edit it in the node editor. seems like its a one material per texture kind of thing. unless im missingsomething

Comment: to give objects different textures but the same material you will have to change materials, yeah.

Comment: i see. thats fine i guess. hopefully it is not too much for the game to handle. thank you