# i made a bench with 15 rectangles intersecting each other and painted it, only 1 was painted even when i group them it doesnt paint the whole thing

Tags: texture-painting, vertex-paint

[image]

right pink object only gets painted/most recently clicked

Comment: Only the active object gets a material assigned. To transfer this material to the other objects while all are still selected, press Ctrl+L > _Link/Transfer Data_ > _Link Materials_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding materials to more than one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34340/adding-materials-to-more-than-one-object)