# Is there a way to flat plane object affecting by proportional edit?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

As in question title, is there a way to flat plane object affecting by proportional edit without creating new plane object?

here my image :

[image]

I don't know how to flat this object except create new plane object or edit position of vertex to z=0 individually.

Comment: Select all vertices of the mesh, press S, then 0 and your mesh'll be flat.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, however I *think* you want to scale along one axis? Try `S` and then `X`, `Y`, or `Z`. Note you may want a custom axis which would make it  a little more difficult but possible.

Comment: I edited my question maybe with picture can explain what I want, if i scale to 0 , my object become single vertex.

Comment: If you want to flatten mesh by one axis, choose it while scaling to 0 (`S` > axis > 0). See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/how-to-flatten-a-face-to-avoid-distortion-make-an-ngon-planar and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33087/bring-all-planes-in-mesh-to-same-level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict the axis in which you scale to zero.

In this case, select all vertices. press:

<kbd>S</kbd> (to activate the scale tool)

<kbd>Z</kbd> (to restrict the scaling to the Z axis)

<kbd>0</kbd> to bring all the vertices to the same plane)

[image]

Comment: thanks, it solve my problem very helpful. But i'm just curious how to tidy that vertex because the result like curve?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to affect one of the mountains in your plane and not the rest? (If Yes, you need to do something like set the 3D cursor and scale a selection of vertices relative to that. Or, the smooth tool in sculpt mode)