# Edit mode refuses to activate

Tags: modeling, workflow

All I did was select bunch of vertices and move them. Then I was supposed to deselect a few of them, but Blender has switched to object mode and I can't activate edit mode anymore. It's not on the list that has the modes and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> does nothing. Anyone know how to avoid this from happening?

Comment: make sure that you only have one object selected, or the object you want is the [active object](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217).

Comment: Are you sure you have the right object selected? Is it possible you could add a screenshot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had  only one object selected. The view itself looked like edit mode. It displayed the vertices and some of them were still selected. I tried to see if it happens again, but now I can't make the object gray again (because it's black when imported), because I'm not really sure how I managed to do that the last time...

Comment: Do you have any armatures on the object?

Comment: What modes are listed in the selection menu? Is this happening on just one object, or on all of your objects?

Comment: Yes there is one armature in the object. I have no idea what it is/does, so I left it alone (the object I'm editing is imported btw).

Answer (score 1):

Like stated in the above comments you probably have more than one object selected, or you might have selected an object that is not editable (eg a light, camera, )Try pressing A a few times and then reselecting your mesh, If you believe it to be a  bug, Try closing blender, starting a new file and importing everything into your new file.