# Is there a way of snapping to edge or face in one direction?

Tags: mesh, snapping

I would like an edge with two vertices to snap to a face which isn't connected. if I move one of the vertices locked to one direction towards the face with face snaps on, i get a snap all along the face, which results in a non-precise snap. I am looking for a way to snap to the face at something like an apparent intersection. Is this possible?

Comment: Related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/snapping-two-objects-by-edge-in-object-mode

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to make that edge snap with both its vertices to the unconnected face?