# Aligning/joining two objects (Head/Body) with matching edge list

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, snapping

I want to align two objects with Blender because for whatever reasons, the head was exported by another program in random orientation. I can easily generate two edge lists which perfectly fit. Knowing the edge lists it should be possible to calculate a the correct orientation of the head, right?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps relevant     https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/snapping-two-objects-by-edge-in-object-mode?rq=1    which is suggested by the web page on the right side.  You may also want to search [Create Orientation].  You may only need 3 vertices to create a plane normal.

Comment: Can you also explain [perfectly fit]? Is this vertex count or length or angles determined by a Script? Casual Inspection?

Comment: You may also want to see [merge].

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Your link does not solve the problem of finding the right orientation, it is only for location. Also Create Orientation does not give me any useful results on BSE.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger
yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my workflow for aligning objects that are accuratelly separated but  rotated randomly. The tutorial seems to be complicated but it is actually quite quick method (if you remember how to do it :) and accurate. Unfortunately I don't know about any addon that would do that automatically.

I will demonstrate it on an example with Suzanne model so warning - this tutorial contains drastical images.

The whole idea is to rotate the model gradually by using 3 common vertices.

1. **Rotate & align both objects so they fit to each other roughly**
   [image]
2. No we need to **find common vertex pair and snap objects there**

   [image]

   Detailed steps:

   - set *Snap target* to *Active* (remember, the *active* vertex / edge / face is the one selected the last)
   - set *Snap Element* to *Vertex* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
   - select the object you are going to fiddle with (it is the top part in our example), switch into *Edit mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then *Select All* <kbd>A</kbd> and select the vertex you are going to use for the snap (now it is the *active* one)
   - enable *Snapping* <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or you can always hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while grabbing instead
   - grab <kbd>G</kbd> the mesh while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move it / snap it to the same positioned vertex in the second model
3. **Use the previously aligned vertex as a pivot point, then snap the model's rotation to the vertex on the other end of the same edge. This needs to be done for each axe separately**
   [image]

   - set *Pivot point* to *3D cursor* <kbd>.</kbd>
   - make sure you have the common vertex selected and move Cursor to Active <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
   - select whole model and then a vertex on the same edge as previously snapped vertex (so it is *active* now)
   - press <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> to rotate around X and snap it to corresponding vertex on the second model, repeat this for Y & Z axes (after that, double-check the mesh doesn't rotate anymore on any of these axes so it is aligned perfectly)
4. **When we have the common edge, we can rotate model around it to make the fit complete**

   - *Pivot Point* to *Active Element*
   - *Transform Orientation* to *Normal*
   - *Snap Target* to *Closest*
   - turn off snapping <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
   - select whole mesh <kbd>A</kbd> and ...
   - select the edge between our previously aligned vertices as last (so it is *active*)
   - rotate the mesh around normal Y axe by pressing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> so it roughly fits the other model
     [image]
   - turn on snapping <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and use the same rotation method as in the previous step, now it will (hopefully) snap perfectly
     [image]

If you are about to join the objects (by selecting them and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), don't forget to go into *Edit Mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all <kbd>A</kbd> and *Remove Doubles* by <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* to merge the common vertices.