# How to connect this, without changing the geometry , can I use snap?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have watched many snap tutorials, and I am not geting it.
For those that have used a 3D cad program might understand my confusion.

The only part I do understand it works totally different.

What is snapping in Blender ?  Is it the origin of an object, snapping to something like a face?

I made a piece of corridor. Copied it, rotated it over 180 degrees and now want to join those two parts. Can this be done with snap?
The parts have the size I want, I don't wanna change the dimensions.

My workflow is like how I would do it in a 3D cad program, but I wonder.
Is there a better Blender way for what I want ?

( I am making a corridor to do something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxUupHWoMLI )

[image: Text]

Comment: Two useful tools to snap: 
 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html?highlight=snap 
and : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/precision.html?highlight=snap

Comment: Do you want to move one end section to snap to the other, or bridge the ends in place?  Do the ends have the same orientation, at the moment?

Comment: I want the second part to move against the first part, no bridge.
 
I just checked, both model origins point the same ways, if that is what you mean?.

Comment: If you want Blender to understand what is supposed to snap, you should first join the 2 objects if it's not already done, then enable Vertex in the Snap options, Target > Active, Project Onto Self and Move options, then select the whole part, make a vertex active, move the mesh and, on the other mesh, point the vertex to which it is supposed to snap

Comment: Thank you, join in object or edit mode ? or does that not matter ?

Comment: I might try to follow some simple tutorials as a test.
I am starting to wonder if there is maybe a problem with my Blender installation.

For now hoping its me not understanding the snap function.
But one thing I notice looking at tutorials, the curser changes, this does not happen for me.

Comment: I found this, so it should be possible.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39784/snapping-two-objects-by-edge-in-object-mode

I had snap working but not yet how I want it. Lets see if the topic in the link can help me. Its what I am trying to do.

Comment: @moonboots 

Thank you, although I have not managed it yet, I think I am starting to understand you're reply.

I for now seem to fail at the select edge part.

Gonna look in the manual and maybe watch some noob tutorials on selecting stuff.
And that round red white crosshair moving. 
I remember seeing a vid were it got mentioned, but I have no idea which vid it was. 
Think it was one the beginner tutorials, I will find it again. 

You're answer is what I was asking for. :)

Comment: One more thing I learned, use G to move your part. For some reason I don't get yet, setting move on the left side of you screen does not work for this.

Comment: We have a winner, I managed to snap the parts. Then the height was a tiny bit off, but I then eyeballed that.

I probably need to play around a bit more with it, because part of me is lost on why it now suddenly did work.
Maybe it was me moving the 3D cursor, that got it going.
Or it has to do with the active object, on which I might have to read the manual.