# Is there a way to copy constraints from one armature to another?

Tags: python, armature, bones, constraints

I have two armatures, all the names and the number of bones are the same, but constraints are configured for one armature, is there a way, perhaps some script to copy the constraints to second armature, without doing it manually, for example, when matching the names of bones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy constraints from one bone to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41709/how-to-copy-constraints-from-one-bone-to-another)

Comment: As far as I can understand, this script copies the constrains within one armature, from left to right, but I need a little different, copy all the constrains from one armature to another armature