# How to copy objects to bounding boxes

Tags: modeling

I have various bounding boxes (lets say 1000 boxes) to which i want to copy my geometry. How do i possibly do this?

Its similar to copying objects from two points. (like moving from centroid of this object to the centroids of the bounding boxes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign same Data to multiple object copies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50155/how-to-assign-same-data-to-multiple-object-copies)

Comment: ... _if_ the bounding boxes have not had their transforms applied