# Blender Texture Paint applying to incorrect object

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I have an object in Blender, and have disabled visibility of all other objects in my scene. It is already  UV mapped and set up with a material. However, whenever I go into texture paint mode, any strokes that I place get applied to the incorrect image (one for another object), even though that object has dissapeared

Here's the interface
[image]

However, whenever I try to paint on it, it gets applied to a completely separate texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *Slots* tab of the tool shelf in texture paint mode.
Now there are two *Painting Modes* here *Material*, which I will talk about first, and *Image*.

[image: Slots tab of the tool shelf in texture paint mode]

When set to *Material* (as in the image above), all *Image Texture* nodes in the selected material are displayed as *Available Paint Slots*. All you have to do is choose the correct "slot" or texture, and paint.

[image: cycles material nodes with the Image Texture node active]

Note that the *Image Texture* node does not have to be connected to anything, and it does not even have to be the [active](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217) node anymore. (yeah!)

---

Now when the *Painting Mode* is set to *Image*, materials no longer matter, only the images. The image field under *Canvas Image*, is where you select what image to paint on. If you don't have on, there is a button to create a new one.
[image: Slots tab of the tool shelf in texture paint mode]

Having said all that, your problem is that you are no painting on the image you think you are.
Just the way you describe how it show up on other objects meas that, you are painting on an image that some other object is using.
Check the painting *Slots* as I explained above.