# How do I parent an object to a vertex which is modified by a curve?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, parent

I'm currently modelling a watch. The strap is curved by a curve modifier. I want to parent the buckle of the strap to the end of the strap so I can change the Bezier curve of the strap and have the buckle move and rotate with it.

the strap (left) with the curve modifier applied:
[image: the strap (left) with the curve modifier applied]

the strap in edit mode:
[image: the strap (left) in edit mode]

I tried parenting the buckle to a vertex of the strap but it doesn't seem to take the curve modifier into account.

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

[MVMT_chrono.blend download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5qPPZJ0oymJREhocDFuRHBzMU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: why don't you join the strap with buckle.Select both meshes and Ctrl+J in object mode.

Comment: joining them would cause the buckle to be deformed by the curve modifier right?

Comment: owh yeah there's that.To create the strap you could use a deform modifier instead of the curve.Then once you've obtained the desired shape apply the mesh deform modifier using a different target(rotate and see the target to get the desired deformation),then join the newly formed shape and the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifiers *do* affect Vertex parents. (Its in my [answer on parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217)). So what you are trying to do is completely possible.

Let me start with the setup. I have a curve object (black curved line top left in the image below). The selected object is the one that will be deformed by the curve, lets call it the "bendy bit." The object on the right is the thing I will vertex parent to the bendy bit.
[image: the three objects in my scene]

With that out of the way, select the "thing" in your case the buckle, then select the strap (or in my case the bendy bit) that way the bendy bit is the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217). Now <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode.

This is how it will look when in edit mode, with another object selected.
[image: in edit mode with another object selected]

Now select three vertices. But not just any three, they have to be near the end with the thing (duh), but they also can not be in a straight line.
See if you select three vertices in a line, that line does not hold enough information to properly convey the orientation to the child object.
[image: proper vertices for vertex parent]
So with three vertices selected, like in the image above, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*.

Now when you turn on the display of the curve modifier you will see the thing on the end follows properly.  You edit the curve, and everything will update live.
[image: final result]

---

Here is a gif of the whole process, just because people live videos:
[image: animated gif showing the process of creating a vertex parent]

Comment: Thank you for your anwer! I think my problem lies somewhere else... When I follow your steps the buckle does not seem to care about moving when I modify the curve.