# Weird selection problem

Tags: selection-tools

I'm having trouble with selecting objects... This never happened before, but now whenever I press 'a' to select everything only one object is highlighted yellow and the others are all highlighted orange, like this:

[image]

Whenever I press shift and right click on the orange object, it turns yellow but the other one turns orange. I can't seem to edit or do anything to the one with the orange outline.

I've done some research and learned that the orange outlines are for objects that are selected but not active, but this problem is annoying me and I haven't found a solution. Is there any way to make all objects editable again?

Thanks!

Comment: This has always been the behaviour in blender, but 'Weird selection problem' isn't a very descriptive title. Can you be clearer about the specific problem you are facing? Is it that you expect to be able to edit both objects at once?

Comment: Yellow and orange colors for selections is a normal behavior. Both are in the selection but the yellow one is unique and is called "active" element and the other(s) are simply selected. When you shift click again on a selected one it become active and if you click again it becomes unselected. Same behavior in edit mode inside a mesh or armature for instance.

Comment: [The active object](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the exact problem. Yellow shows the active selected object, while orange shows the selected objects that are not the active ones, you can only edit the active object. If you want to edit the two cubes at the same time then you can join them as one object using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> then after doing what you want you can separate them again by switching to edit mode and selecting all vertices using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>V</kbd> then `Separate by loose parts`

Comment: I just though that it was weird that this suddenly happened, because before I was able to make all objects on the screen active like this: http://imgur.com/a/FmQJ0

Comment: That is a single object in edit mode, not multiple objects

Comment: @Higgsboson728 as I mentioned in my answer and as DuarteFarrajotaRamos  mentioned as well, you can't edit multiple objects at the same time, the screenshot you have is of a single object not multiple ones.