# BGE: Turn Physics off globally while keeping sensors

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

I'm working on a Jump'n'Run kind of game and came to the conclusion that I'm better of doing physics myself. (I'm using python for movement/logic anyway.)

So I'd like to turn the physics engine off completely, that is no collisions, no gravity, no friction (!) and so on.

I tried disabling the physics engine switching from "Bullet" to "None" but this kind of removes my sensors which are parented to the player.

So what do I have to do to tell Bullet to leave me alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the bullet physic engine to have many parts of the bge work, so don't disable that. Simply set all your objects to [Static](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/physics/types/static.html) *Physic Type*. You will need to enable *Actor* and *Ghost* on them too.

[image: BGE Physic settings]

The static physic type does not react to physics (no gravity, friction, etc). Actor lets the logic bricks "see" the object, and Ghost disables collisions.

With those three options on all your objects you should have a clean slate to build your own interactions off of.

---

To edit the physics properties on all your objects:

First set up *one* object like I describe above. Select all the objects, and keep the one you just edited the physics settings as the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217). Now press <kbd>space</kbd> and type "copy" choose "*Copy Game Physics Properties to Selected*". That's it, all the objects are set the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Sure that there aren't any "more global" options.  I've got a heck of objects. (The game is build pretty oldschool with tiles.)

Comment: @Scheintod see my edited answer. super easy to set all the physics properties.